# What does selectAll actually do in a force layout diagram?

Tags: d3.js

I have the following code...

```
 nodes = svg.selectAll("node")
            .data(graph.nodes)
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("r", 10)
            .call(force.drag)
            .style("fill", "red");
```

So I get that `.data` binds the data and `.enter` creates a circle with the proper properties for each node. But what is the first selectAll doing? I see no node class or anything anywhere.

Comment: Have you seen [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/)?

Comment: Given the corrections from @Mark, it comes into play when you _update_ the data.  You need to cast your mind forward to what needs to happen when you hit that code with _revised data_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your code it won't do much since that'll select an element of `node` which doesn't exist.  This won't affect the `enter().append` but would break on any re-selection updating.

If I was you I'd code it as:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node") //<-- notice the class selectory
  .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "node") //<-- and put the class on them, so we can reselect them later
  ...
```

This is how it's done in Bostock's [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045).